# Can i get specific value from string using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am having a string and I want to get a specific value from it.

```
@string = "[ewqewe]wwerc:[value1]&31545415151|erertrtc:[value2]&nbmnbmn|uiuoiuoioioc:[value3]s:[value4]pupup[vfdvdfv]fbdbdbbdbddbdbdbdbc:[value5]&uiiouops:[value6]"
```

I just want to extract a value that is coming after c: and s: inside[ ] but it must exclude [vfdvdfv] and [ewqewe] because it not coming with c: and s:

```
%%[

    var @ss @pattern @value1, @value2, @value3, @value4, @value5, @value6

    set @ss = '"[ewqewe]wwerc:[value1]&31545415151|erertrtc:[value2]&nbmnbmn|uiuoiuoioioc:[value3]s:[value4]pupup[vfdvdfv]fbdbdbbdbddbdbdbdbc:[value5]&uiiouops:[value6]"'


set @pattern = '^.*[ewqewe]wwerc:(.*)&31545415151|erertrtc:(.*)&nbmnbmn|uiuoiuoioioc:(.*)s:(.*)pupup[vfdvdfv]fbdbdbbdbddbdbdbdbc:(.*)&uiiouops:(.*)'

    set @value1 = RegExMatch(@ss, @pattern, 1)

    set @value2 = RegExMatch(@ss, @pattern, 2)

    set @value3 = RegExMatch(@ss, @pattern, 3)

    set @value4 = RegExMatch(@ss, @pattern, 4)

    set @value5 = RegExMatch(@ss, @pattern, 5)

    set @value6 = RegExMatch(@ss, @pattern, 6)

]%%

value1:%%=v(@value1)=%%<br>
value2:%%=v(@value2)=%%<br>
value3:%%=v(@value3)=%%<br>
value4:%%=v(@value4)=%%<br>
value5:%%=v(@value5)=%%<br>
value6:%%=v(@value6)=%%<br>
```

Can Someone correct this so that it will give result like

> value1:value1
>
> value2:value2
>
> value3:value3
>
> value4:value4
>
> value5:value5
>
> value6:value6

Comment: If you could update your question with any attempts you've already made -- functional or not, it'll help us help you.

Comment: Hi Adam, i have updated my question will you please correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You will need to use Regular Expressions, however (regex).

Have a look at the [Ampscript RegEx Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/RegExMatch.htm).

Comment: Thanks Timothy, Will you please share the code how i can modified it

Comment: There are more examples here: https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch

Comment: Or just search for regexmatch on salesforce stack exchange